# Boolean label can not be used without a boolean index

Tags: pandas

Running `find_customer_referee(customer)` returns `KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'`

```
data = [[1, 'Will', None], [2, 'Jane', None], [3, 'Alex', 2], [4, 'Bill', None], [5, 'Zack', 1], [6, 'Mark', 2]]
customer = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'name', 'referee_id']).astype({'id':'Int64', 'name':'object', 'referee_id':'Int64'})

def find_customer_referee(customer: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return customer.loc[(customer.referee_id is None),['name']]
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) instead `is None` comparing, because working with array, not scalar:

```
def find_customer_referee(customer: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return customer.loc[customer.referee_id.isna(),['name']]
```